# Why can't our app store a simple key/value pair in iCloud?

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud

I've configured our app for iCloud usage with the appropriate entitlements, under a provisioning profile that is set up for iCloud, and a developer profile that's associated with this provisioning profile.

The application identifier matches what's specified in the provisioning profile (com.ourcompany.ourproduct).  I don't get any errors when building the app.

iCloud is enabled on my phone, and is working (as evidenced by my calendar, contacts, and bookmarks being updated).

And yet this fails (localID is a valid NSString):

```
       NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore* iCloudStore = [NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore
defaultStore];
       [iCloudStore setString:localID forKey:@"ourKey"];
```

If I call synchronize after this, it returns NO.  If I allow plenty of
time for the update to occur, subsequent attempts to retrieve the data
still fail.

Any idea what the culprit could be here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In the simulator, NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore will just store values on disk and won't even try to synchronize anything.

On the device, synchronize will generally fail because your kvstore-identifier entitlement is incorrectly set but you should then see an error log in your Console.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I'm running on the phone.  I eventually had to use a support incident for this.  The Apple rep gave me a couple of commands to activate iCloud logging, and THIS caused the error to be cleared.  We never determined what was broken, but I didn't change a single line of code or project setting.

Comment: How do you turn on iCloud logging?

Answer (score 2):

Are you running it in the simulator? iCloud sync doesn't appear to work in the simulator, only on a device.  Beyond that, your code looks good.  I would expect it to work.

I also noticed that I was able to store and retrieve keys even before I set up my entitlements.  I'm assuming the entitlements just allow you to link a key-value store to your App ID so that multiple devices or multiple apps from your company can share a store.

Knowing this, you could try completely removing references to iCloud in your entitlements and see if that works. Just for testing purposes.

Comment: Thanks.  I was running on the phone.  Please see my comment above.  I've left this question open only because we never determined what the original problem was.